# how to get height of band using autoheight powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a datawindows with 2 groups, I set one of the groups header band with autoheight and check and set one of the columns on that header band with the autoheight column also.

I want to make a vertical line 'grew' height as the column 'grew' with autoheight on it. Is it posible to do this in datawindow? or must it be done using a powerscript?

Answer (score 0):

you can make it with the help of the datawindow expressions. Let's suppose that you have a column with the name of "test" and want your line to has the same height as the "test" column,

1. click on the line object on the datawindow which you want verticaly resize
2. Click on the Position tabpage
3. There is a small box at the end of the line 'Y1' click on it
4. In the popup window put this in the expression field: `integer(describe("test.y"))` and click ok
5. There is a small box at the end of the line 'Y2' click on it
6. In the popup window put this in the expression field: `integer(describe("test.y")) + integer(describe("test.height"))` and click ok

And this was the magic! Feel free to ask!

Regards Gábor

Ps.:

Here is the full syntax of the datawindow. Lets try to create it and test it:

```
release 12.5;
datawindow(units=0 timer_interval=0 color=1073741824 brushmode=0 transparency=0 gradient.angle=0 gradient.color=8421504 gradient.focus=0 gradient.repetition.count=0 gradient.repetition.length=100 gradient.repetition.mode=0 gradient.scale=100 gradient.spread=100 gradient.transparency=0 picture.blur=0 picture.clip.bottom=0 picture.clip.left=0 picture.clip.right=0 picture.clip.top=0 picture.mode=0 picture.scale.x=100 picture.scale.y=100 picture.transparency=0 processing=0 HTMLDW=no print.printername="" print.documentname="" print.orientation = 0 print.margin.left = 110 print.margin.right = 110 print.margin.top = 96 print.margin.bottom = 96 print.paper.source = 0 print.paper.size = 0 print.canusedefaultprinter=yes print.prompt=no print.buttons=no print.preview.buttons=no print.cliptext=no print.overrideprintjob=no print.collate=yes print.background=no print.preview.background=no print.preview.outline=yes hidegrayline=no showbackcoloronxp=no picture.file="" )
header(height=292 color="536870912" transparency="0" gradient.color="8421504" gradient.transparency="0" gradient.angle="0" brushmode="0" gradient.repetition.mode="0" gradient.repetition.count="0" gradient.repetition.length="100" gradient.focus="0" gradient.scale="100" gradient.spread="100" )
summary(height=0 color="536870912" transparency="0" gradient.color="8421504" gradient.transparency="0" gradient.angle="0" brushmode="0" gradient.repetition.mode="0" gradient.repetition.count="0" gradient.repetition.length="100" gradient.focus="0" gradient.scale="100" gradient.spread="100" )
footer(height=0 color="536870912" transparency="0" gradient.color="8421504" gradient.transparency="0" gradient.angle="0" brushmode="0" gradient.repetition.mode="0" gradient.repetition.count="0" gradient.repetition.length="100" gradient.focus="0" gradient.scale="100" gradient.spread="100" )
detail(height=84 color="536870912" transparency="0" gradient.color="8421504" gradient.transparency="0" gradient.angle="0" brushmode="0" gradient.repetition.mode="0" gradient.repetition.count="0" gradient.repetition.length="100" gradient.focus="0" gradient.scale="100" gradient.spread="100" )
table(column=(type=char(10) updatewhereclause=yes name=test dbname="test" )
 )
column(band=header id=1 alignment="0" tabsequence=10 border="2" color="33554432" x="9" y="36" height="124" width="274" format="[general]" html.valueishtml="0"  name=test visible="1" edit.limit=0 edit.case=any edit.autoselect=yes edit.autohscroll=yes  font.face="Tahoma" font.height="-10" font.weight="400"  font.family="2" font.pitch="2" font.charset="0" background.mode="1" background.color="536870912" background.transparency="0" background.gradient.color="8421504" background.gradient.transparency="0" background.gradient.angle="0" background.brushmode="0" background.gradient.repetition.mode="0" background.gradient.repetition.count="0" background.gradient.repetition.length="100" background.gradient.focus="0" background.gradient.scale="100" background.gradient.spread="100" tooltip.backcolor="134217752" tooltip.delay.initial="0" tooltip.delay.visible="32000" tooltip.enabled="0" tooltip.hasclosebutton="0" tooltip.icon="0" tooltip.isbubble="0" tooltip.maxwidth="0" tooltip.textcolor="134217751" tooltip.transparency="0" transparency="0" )
line(band=header x1="306" y1="0~tinteger(describe(~"test.y~"))" x2="306" y2="32~tinteger(describe(~"test.y~")) + integer(describe(~"test.height~"))"  name=l_1 visible="1" pen.style="0" pen.width="23" pen.color="33554432"  background.mode="2" background.color="1073741824" background.transparency="0" background.gradient.color="8421504" background.gradient.transparency="0" background.gradient.angle="0" background.brushmode="0" background.gradient.repetition.mode="0" background.gradient.repetition.count="0" background.gradient.repetition.length="100" background.gradient.focus="0" background.gradient.scale="100" background.gradient.spread="100" tooltip.backcolor="134217752" tooltip.delay.initial="0" tooltip.delay.visible="32000" tooltip.enabled="0" tooltip.hasclosebutton="0" tooltip.icon="0" tooltip.isbubble="0" tooltip.maxwidth="0" tooltip.textcolor="134217751" tooltip.transparency="0" )
compute(band=header alignment="0" expression="Describe(~"test.y~")"border="2" color="33554432" x="475" y="100" height="64" width="215" format="[GENERAL]" html.valueishtml="0"  name=compute_1 visible="1"  font.face="Tahoma" font.height="-10" font.weight="400"  font.family="2" font.pitch="2" font.charset="0" background.mode="2" background.color="1073741824" background.transparency="0" background.gradient.color="8421504" background.gradient.transparency="0" background.gradient.angle="0" background.brushmode="0" background.gradient.repetition.mode="0" background.gradient.repetition.count="0" background.gradient.repetition.length="100" background.gradient.focus="0" background.gradient.scale="100" background.gradient.spread="100" tooltip.backcolor="134217752" tooltip.delay.initial="0" tooltip.delay.visible="32000" tooltip.enabled="0" tooltip.hasclosebutton="0" tooltip.icon="0" tooltip.isbubble="0" tooltip.maxwidth="0" tooltip.textcolor="134217751" tooltip.transparency="0" transparency="0" )
compute(band=header alignment="0" expression="Describe(~"test.height~")"border="2" color="33554432" x="471" y="16" height="64" width="215" format="[GENERAL]" html.valueishtml="0"  name=compute_2 visible="1"  font.face="Tahoma" font.height="-10" font.weight="400"  font.family="2" font.pitch="2" font.charset="0" background.mode="2" background.color="1073741824" background.transparency="0" background.gradient.color="8421504" background.gradient.transparency="0" background.gradient.angle="0" background.brushmode="0" background.gradient.repetition.mode="0" background.gradient.repetition.count="0" background.gradient.repetition.length="100" background.gradient.focus="0" background.gradient.scale="100" background.gradient.spread="100" tooltip.backcolor="134217752" tooltip.delay.initial="0" tooltip.delay.visible="32000" tooltip.enabled="0" tooltip.hasclosebutton="0" tooltip.icon="0" tooltip.isbubble="0" tooltip.maxwidth="0" tooltip.textcolor="134217751" tooltip.transparency="0" transparency="0" )
htmltable(border="1" )
htmlgen(clientevents="1" clientvalidation="1" clientcomputedfields="1" clientformatting="0" clientscriptable="0" generatejavascript="1" encodeselflinkargs="1" netscapelayers="0" pagingmethod=0 generatedddwframes="1" )
xhtmlgen() cssgen(sessionspecific="0" )
xmlgen(inline="0" )
xsltgen()
jsgen()
export.xml(headgroups="1" includewhitespace="0" metadatatype=0 savemetadata=0 )
import.xml()
export.pdf(method=0 distill.custompostscript="0" xslfop.print="0" )
export.xhtml()
```

Is it working now as you wanted?

Comment: when The column 'GREW' height but the vertical line still the same height. I put a computed field to check weather your describe height is 'grew' or not. 'integer(describe("test.height"))', sadly it isn't 'grew'. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You should try : `rowheight()`

Or using powerscript

Comment: provide link to references if possible!